# When does a probability measure take all values in the unit interval?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$. Are there conditions on the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ such that for every real number $c\in [0,1]$ we find a set $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mathbb{P}(A)=c$. 
It is like the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A measure space $(\mathbb{P},\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ is atomless if for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mathbb{P}(A)>0$ there exists $B\subset A, B\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $0<\mathbb{P}(B)<\mathbb{P}(A)$. Now according to a theorem of Sierpinski, the values of an atomless measure space form an interval. In particular, for probability spaces, every value in $[0,1]$ is taken. The original source of the article can be found [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm3/fm3125.pdf) (in french). For a proof in english, you can look at on 215D on page 46 in Fremlin's book [Measure Theory 2](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.116.7816&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: So, the condition holds on spaces where the total mass of the atoms is at most 1/2, and on spaces where the sums of the atoms have gaps of width at most the mass of the space excluding atoms.

Answer (score 6):

A necessary and sufficient condition is that every atom is no larger than the sum of all smaller atoms, plus the non-atomic part.

Comment: In particular a measure consisting only of atoms of mass $1/2, 1/4, 1/8, \ldots$ just barely suffices.

Answer (score 4):

This is a property of $\mu$, not that of $\mathcal A$, and it is called being atomless. It is equivalent to not having sets $A \in \mathcal A$ of positive measure such that for all $B \in \mathcal A$, $B \subseteq A$ the measure $\mu(B)$ is either 0 or $\mu(A)$.

edit: [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom%5F%28measure%5Ftheory%29), complete with the proof of the property you describe from atomlessness.

edit: yup, the comments are right and I'm wrong. The precise condition for finite measures composed entirely of atoms to have full range is $a_n \leq \sum_{j>n} a_j$ - it is clearly necessary as $a_n-\varepsilon$ has to be produced somehow, and the greedy algorithm shows sufficiency.

Comment: In fact, certain atomic measures also have range [0,1], so "atomless" is sufficient but not necessary.


Comment: If you take a measure made up purely of atoms (the atoms having measures (a_1, a_2, a_3...) in decreasing order, what are the conditions guaranteeing full range?  For example, a_i <= 2a_{i+1} suffices, but may not be necessary

Answer (score 4):

Here's a concrete example of an atomless measure.  Let $f \in L^1$ be an integrable function with total mass 1 (i.e. $\int_0^1 f = 1$).  Define $$\mathbb P(A) = \int_A f(x) ~dx$$ for any Borel set $A$.  It is a nice exercise to show that $\mathbb P$ is an atomless measure.

Note:  $f$ is called the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mathbb P$ with respect to Lebesgue measure, and often written $f = \tfrac{d\mathbb P}{dx}$.  If a random variable $X$ has distribution $\mathbb P$, then $f$ is called its density function.

Comment: @TG: Instead of "Exercise: Prove...", maybe "It is a nice exercise to show..." or something like that?

Comment: Pete, I like your rephrasing.  I'll change my post.

Comment: Only a mathematician would start a concrete example with "Let $f \in L^1$..."